# Open File Dialog not working

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am trying to add a filter `OpenFileDialog` control but after  using filter. There is no file just folders . Without filter everything is ok. What can i do?

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       OpenFileDialog fileChooser = new OpenFileDialog();
       fileChooser.Filter = " Image File (*.jpeg)|(*.jpeg)|  All Files  (*.*) |(*.*)";
       if (fileChooser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = fileChooser.FileName;
       }
  }
```

Comment: see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why not use FolderBrowserDialog? http://www.dotnetperls.com/folderbrowserdialog

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just don't use brackets when defining the file-extension.

```
fileChooser.Filter = "Image File (*.jpg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|All Files|*.*";
```

Comment: there's no other error in your code. Are you sure you want to use `jpeg` as extension and not `jpg`? Because last one is more common and I don't know what could be wrong otherwise.